# Mac OS X Server Xcode Bot Issue

Tags: ios, iphone, osx-server, xcode-bots

I've successfully integrated CI on my Mac OS X server, but my bot actually build wrong.
I guess, that it should build archive with selected 'Release' Configuration, but it uses Debug configuration instead. Did someone faced with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, need to checkmark 'Perform Archive action' when creating/editing bot. This will cause performing Debug->Release Build configuration. If also check 'Perform Analyze/Test action' it will be: Debug->Analyze->Test->Archive.

Answer (score 1):

The bot runs using configurations set the scheme it starts off of.  If the scheme sets the archive configuration to Release, the bot should build in Release.  Edit the scheme to archive in debug build configuration, and you should see your bot build an archive in debug build configuration.

The following shows the edit scheme window.  This scheme's archive  phase uses the release build config.

[image]